# How can I sort my Jquery dropdownlist by date created?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint-2010

I have a sharepoint dropdown that I need ordered by date created. The code I have so far tried is this simple JQuery:

```
function DashboardReport(a, b) {
    return new Date(a.Created).getTime() - new Date(b.Created).getTime();
}
```

This is the html sharepoint dropdown I want to re-order:

```
    <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1753" ControlMode="New" FieldName="DashboardReport" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i','ff1753','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@DashboardReport')}" />
```